# runZonedGuarded in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bloc

```
// Copyright (c) 2021, Very Good Ventures
// https://verygood.ventures
//
// Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style
// license that can be found in the LICENSE file or at
// https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT.

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class AppBlocObserver extends BlocObserver {
  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase bloc, Change change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);
    log('onChange(${bloc.runtimeType}, $change)');
  }

  @override
  void onError(BlocBase bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    log('onError(${bloc.runtimeType}, $error, $stackTrace)');
    super.onError(bloc, error, stackTrace);
  }
}

Future<void> bootstrap(FutureOr<Widget> Function() builder) async {
  Bloc.observer = AppBlocObserver();
  FlutterError.onError = (details) {
    log(details.exceptionAsString(), stackTrace: details.stack);
  };

  await runZonedGuarded(
    () async => runApp(await builder()),
    (error, stackTrace) => log(error.toString(), stackTrace: stackTrace),
  );
}
```

Can someone explain this code snippet, I am just confused with runZonedGuarded() and bootstrap(FutureOr Function() builder). This code generated by very_good CLI, which will create a starter boilerplate for flutter app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Future<void> bootstrap(FutureOr<Widget> Function() builder) async { ...`

is defining a function called `bootstrap`. This function takes a parameter called builder that is a

- function taking no parameters
- returning a Future or a Widget

and it will execute asynchronously (builder may or may not execute asynchronously).

The `Bloc.observer = AppBlocObserver();` is a deprecated way of observing what the bloc(s) of the application are doing. The `AppBlocObserver` is defining a bunch of callbacks that will be executed when "events" are fired, like `error`, and `change`.

With version >= [8.0 of the BLoC- library](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc/changelog) you should likely do something like below instead of the run zone guarded postend in the question, since they moved the bloc observer property.

```
runZonedGuarded(
  () => BlocOverrides.runZoned(
    () async => runApp(await builder()), 
    blocObserver: AppBlocObserver()
  ),
  (error, stackTrace) => log(error.toString(), stackTrace: stackTrace));
```

This 'builder' method that's potentially an async method - or not - is then going to be executed and the returning widget is going to be the parameter to [runApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/runApp.html) - witch is going to

> Inflate the given widget and attach it to the screen.

That app is then going to be run in an [error zone](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/runZonedGuarded.html), where the interesting part is

> The onError function is used both to handle asynchronous errors by overriding ZoneSpecification.handleUncaughtError in zoneSpecification, if any, and to handle errors thrown synchronously by the call to body.

Comment: **UPDATE:**

`Bloc.observer` was reintroduced in 8.1.0 and `BlocOverrides` was deprecated.